# Using ubuntu 18.04 while launching android automotive emulator getting issue

Tags: 18.04, android-emulator

I am unable to launch the android automotive emulator in ubuntu 18.04, without getting the following error:

```
Emulator: [swscaler @ 0x3e02000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
```

Is there any solution for the above error?

I have tried with installing ffmpeg but still I am getting this issue.

Also I have followed this link in android developer site

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-haxm-intel

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

System details:
Memory 31.3 GiB
Processor Intel core i7 - 7700 CPU @3.60Ghz x8
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2)
GNOME 3.28.2
OS type 64 bit
Disk 950.7 GB

It would be really helpful if any solution for this link.